# My image disappear when i run jar file

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, embedded-resource

well here are the classes i made..

```
package testdnevnik;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Diary {

  StartWindow startWindow = new StartWindow();

  static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Diary");

  int n = 0;

  public Diary() {

     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setResizable(false);
     frame.setSize(800,600);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     //frame.add(new ImagePanel("Img//bg2.jpeg"));
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.add(startWindow);

     startWindow.checkStudents(n);
     startWindow.chooseOption();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Diary();  
  }

}
```

that was the main class,and here is the panel for the start window..

```
package testdnevnik;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import static testdnevnik.Diary.frame;

public class StartWindow extends JPanel {

  JPanel jp = new JPanel();
  JLabel jl = new JLabel();
  JLabel headline = new JLabel();
  JButton viewStudents = new JButton();
  JButton editStudents = new JButton();
  JButton addStudents = new JButton();
  JButton removeStudents = new JButton();
  JLabel usernameLbl = new JLabel();
  JLabel passwordLbl = new JLabel();
  JTextField usernameFld = new JTextField();
  JPasswordField passwordFld = new JPasswordField();
  JButton logIn = new JButton("Log In");
  JButton signUp = new JButton("Sign Up");

  public StartWindow () {


  jp.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

 // headline
 headline.setText("Diary");
 headline.setLocation(200, 30);
 headline.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
 headline.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 60));
 headline.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
 headline.setSize(300, 80);
 headline.setVisible(true);

  // Buttons
 //View Students - Button
 viewStudents.setText("View All Students");
 viewStudents.setSize(200,40);
 viewStudents.setLocation(70 , 200);
 viewStudents.setVisible(true);

  // Edit Students - Button
 editStudents.setText("Edit Students");
 editStudents.setSize(200,40);
 editStudents.setLocation(70 , 300);
 editStudents.setVisible(true);

  // Add Students - Button
 addStudents.setText("Add New Students");
 addStudents.setSize(200,40);
 addStudents.setLocation(70 ,400);
 addStudents.setVisible(true);

  // Remove Students - Button
 removeStudents.setText("Remove Students");
 removeStudents.setSize(200,40);
 removeStudents.setLocation(70 , 500);
 removeStudents.setVisible(true);

 // username and password labels and input field
 usernameLbl.setText("Username: ");
 usernameLbl.setBounds(320, 200, 108, 40);
 usernameLbl.setFont(new Font(null,Font.BOLD, 20));
 usernameLbl.setVisible(true);
 usernameFld.setBounds(450, 205, 200, 30); // username field input
 usernameFld.setVisible(true);

 passwordLbl.setText("Password: ");
 passwordLbl.setBounds(320, 300, 108, 40);
 passwordLbl.setFont(new Font(null,Font.BOLD, 20));
 passwordLbl.setVisible(true);
 passwordFld.setBounds(450, 305, 200, 30); // password field input
 passwordFld.setVisible(true);

 // button for log in and sign up
 logIn.setBounds(580, 400, 70, 40);
 logIn.setVisible(true);
 signUp.setBounds(480, 400, 90, 40);
 signUp.setVisible(true);

 // panel
 jp.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));

 jp.add(viewStudents); // add ViewStudents button to the panel
 jp.add(editStudents); // add EditStudents button to the panel
 jp.add(addStudents); // add AddStudents button to the panel
 jp.add(removeStudents); // add RemoveStudents button to the panel
 jp.add(usernameLbl); // username label
 jp.add(passwordLbl); // password label
 jp.add(usernameFld); // username input field
 jp.add(passwordFld); // password input field
 jp.add(logIn); //add log in button to the panel
 jp.add(signUp); //add sign up button to the panel
 jp.add(headline); // add headline label to the panel
 jp.add(new ImagePanel("Img//bg2.jpg")); // add background image to the panel

 // adding panel to the frame
 frame.add(jp);

 validate();
}

  public void checkStudents(int n) {
     int numberOfStudents = n;
        if (numberOfStudents == 0) {
           removeStudents.setEnabled(false);
     }
  }

  public void chooseOption() {

     viewStudents.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "view students", "alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
  });

     editStudents.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "edit students", "alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
  });

     addStudents.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "add students", "alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
  });

     removeStudents.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "remove students", "alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
  });

     logIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "succesful log in", "alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
     });

     signUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sign up form", "alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
     });

  }

}
```

and here is the class for the image background

```
package testdnevnik;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

private Image img;

public ImagePanel(String img) {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
}

public ImagePanel(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    setPreferredSize(size);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

when i run the program from the NetBeans everything is ok,running perfectly,but when i click "Clean and Build Project" in NetBeans and run from the jar file in the folder,the background is white but the components added to the panel are fine,just the image for the background disappearing,why??

Comment: The `ImagePanel` is attempting to load the image by `File` rather than `URL`.  This comes up a couple of times a day.  AFAIU there are also lots of other problems with the code (like trying to use `setBounds(..)` in conjunction with `BorderLayout`).

Comment: As @AndrewThompson mentions, using `File` is a bad idea (well, in 2015 it's a bad idea full stop) when referring to resources which are on the classpath. What you should use is `.getResource{,AsStream}()` so that your code be independent of the "storage medium" of your image. And yes, this problem is very, very common.